# Is there an html entity equivalent of ▼?

Tags: html, entity

Like `&nbsp;`.

And what about other symbols?

Comment: [&nabla;](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_symbol) is the hollow nabla.

Comment: Which looks like this: `∇`

Answer (score 5):

You can specify any unicode character using its character code, eg:

₥ is U+20A5, and you can mark it up like this `&#x20A5;`

Check out this [list of unicode characters](http://theorem.ca/~mvcorks/code/charsets/auto.html) for more examples.

▼ is `&#x25BC;`, btw.

Answer (score 4):

OR ▼ `&#9660;`

This is how I usually do on Windows. Using Character Map:

[image: Character Map]

**U+25BC** is the hex number for the unicode character. So either I use `&#x25bc;` or convert to decimal and use `&#9660;`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the full list for HTML 4 from the standard itself: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html

Otherwise, use the `&#xNN;` syntax, where `NN` is the hexidecimal representation (can be more than two characters) of the unicode character.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your title question is probably no.  The entire list of HTML4 entities can be found at:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html

Of course, you're free to use Unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.natural-innovations.com/wa/doc-charset.html